# Singular strong generator

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals

Let $V$ be a model of $\mathrm{ZFC}$ and let $j\colon V \to M$ be an elementary embedding with a critical point $\kappa$ ($M$ is transitive). A *strong generator* of $j$ is an ordinal $\zeta \geq \kappa$ such that for all $f\colon \zeta \to \zeta$ in $V$, and for all $\xi < \zeta$, $j(f)(\xi) < \zeta$.

Let $\kappa$ be the critical point of $j$. It is easy to see that $\kappa$ is the least strong generator of $j$ and that the second strong generator is $$\kappa_1 = \sup \{j(f)(\kappa) \mid f\colon \kappa \to \kappa\}.$$

**Question:** What is the consistency strength of "$M \models \kappa_1$ is singular"?

**Remark:** One can obtain an upper bound from a large cardinal axiom slightly weaker than $1$-extendibility.

Comment: The answer, of course, is three. The consistency strength is three.